# Оптимизация mysql запроса, при выводе большого к-ва данных

Tags: php, mysql, big-data

На одну страницу, при её загрузке нужно вывести:
Данные из аккаунта, которые я получаю по API, что включает в себя расшифровку json файла и загрузку на страницу около 100 картинок, так в добавок нужно на эту же страницу вывести около 4000(!) картинок и названий из базы данных (mysql). И это всё сразу при загрузке страницы !

Когда я перехожу на эту страницу при обычных условиях (просто вывел данные из базы и просто расшифровал json на месте), то секунд 10 сначала грузится сам переход, а поотм ещё секунд 20 сама страница. На некоторых сайтах видел как переход происходит моментально, а данные как будто подгружаются постепенно в своём блоке. При этом это никак практически не влияет на загрузку остальных элементов на странице. Подскажите пожалуйста, что это за магия такая и как её гуглить ?

Comment: Видимо надо избавится от json, если он большой, оптимизировать запросы к БД. Что бы HTML часть страницы генерилась моментально. А картинки отдавать NGINX и ссылки на них на странице должны быть статическими, т.е. без знака `?` в URL (без вызова скриптов). И в дополнение можно реализовать создание элементов img на странице по мере прокрутки (это уже на JS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эту магию можно реализовать, например, если сперва грузить просто структуру страницы без тяжелых данных, например только текстовые данные аккаунта. После же, когда страница загрузится, можно Ajax запросом подгружать остальное и вставлять в заранее приготовленные блоки.

При использовании jQuery, Ajax запрос отправлять внутри:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      // Ajax
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Если картинки надо просто показать как есть без дальнейших операции с ними (например - нажал - увеличилась и так далее...), то перед выводом сделайте из картинок ОДНУ! Я так формирую порядка 7000 картинок - миниэскизы - в одну картинку, время на обработку 0,01-0,1 сек, вывод на экран мгновенно. Библиотечку GD пощупайте, там методы на все случаи жизни. Для ориентира посмотрите вывод миниатюр на букинг-ком - там 20-50 мини-картинок к каждому отелю-гостинице и т.д идет как одна длинная картинка.